# Why is Tr$(A (\vec{1}\vec{1}^T)B (\vec{1}\vec{1}^T)) = \mathrm{Tr}(A (\vec{1}\vec{1}^T))\mathrm{Tr}(B (\vec{1}\vec{1}^T))$ for all matrices $A,B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

Suppose $(\vec1 \vec 1^T)$ denote the matrix of ones. I noticed while doing numerics that $\mathrm{Tr}(A (\vec{1}\vec{1}^T)B (\vec{1}\vec{1}^T)) = \mathrm{Tr}(A (\vec{1}\vec{1}^T))\mathrm{Tr}(B (\vec{1}\vec{1}^T))$ for all matrices $A,B$ I was working on. Why is that? Can we prove it easily?

Comment: The trace is invariance under cyclic permutations. Hence $\operatorname{tr} ( A e e^T ) = \operatorname{tr} (e^T A e) = e^T A e$.

Comment: Oh, you're saying cyclic permuatiton possible even when the matrices are not square, i .e. if A is mxn, B is nxk and C is kxl, then Tr(ABC) = Tr(CAB) = Tr(BCA)?

Comment: Yup. ${}{}{}{}$